# How to check if model has an attribute (OneToOneField) with queryset?

Tags: django

I am using the default `User` model with `Agent` acting as a OneToOne profile model.  I want to create a queryset of all users who has Agent as a field.  I'm aware of `hasattr` but it returns a True/False boolean value so I couldn't implement that into my query.

views

```
class AgentSearchResults(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'agent_search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(AgentSearchResults, self).get_queryset()
        # Write something here to check if all users in 'queryset' has 'agent'.
        return queryset
```

models for reference

```
class Agent(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='agent')
```

Comment: By default the OneToOneField is going to force you to associate an user to each agent. You need to use `user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='agent')`. Once done that, you can go with @Bear Brown suggestion.

Comment: @slackmart when you create an `User` instance you don't need to create an instance for any related models with `OneToOne` relation.

Comment: Yep Sir. My previous comment is saying Django will expect an existing user to associate with each agent (scenario: an agent is being created).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter by check is related model's pk is null

```
User.objects.filter(agent__pk__isnull=False)
```

For your case:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(AgentSearchResults, self).get_queryset()
    # Write something here to check if all users in 'queryset' has 'agent'.
    queryset = queryset.filter(agent__pk__isnull=False)
    return queryset
```

Comment: In the expression `queryset.filter(agent__pk__isnull=False)` . Replace 'pk' with any attribute, to check if it exists on the object.